# If web app works fine in Safari, why also test it in iOS simulator?

Tags: xcode, safari, ios-simulator, mobile-safari

I am building a cross-platform mobile app in jQueryMobile and PhoneGap and am currently preparing the iPhone/iPad release. The Phonegap docs suggest I deploy to iOS simulator before deploying to a device http://phonegap.com/start

My app doesn't do a whole lot of device-dependent stuff, though it does use the vibrate function. Basically it's just a packaged website that uses local storage.

When I deploy to simulator, I run into problems that don't occur when I test the app through the Safari browser (I tested Safari on Windows, iMac and iPad).

Since all sources say that Safari works identically on all devices, I am tempted to think that I can ignore problems tht only occur in the highly unnatural context of a mobile device OS simulator running on a laptop.

Am I right? If it works in Safari, why still test a web app in iOS simulator?

Comment: We recently had issues with JWPlayer (a javascript plugin) with safari. It worked fine on a dekstop safari browsers and android browser. But on an actual iPhone it was very buggy.
So I recommend you from personal experience to test it on a real i-device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What problems do you get? Don't think because it works in browser it will in your app :P

Comment: The first problem I am running into: jQueryMobile buttons whose event handler is bound after documentready using .on() do not respond. They do respond in Safari (and in a tested and published Android web app, and every desktop browser).

Comment: Okay, I got past this one roadblock (which was in the user's setup process) and this allowed me to test the whole app and find all sorts of little iOS bugs that weren't coming through in any of the Safari flavors. Thanks for the nudge!

Comment: No problem :) Always test on the platform you are deploying on :D